# XML serialization troubles

Tags: c#, serialization

so i have this problem i`m trying to serialize my classes to the point that they will look like this:

```
    <orders>
       <order>
           <ordersID>22070</ordersID>
           <ordersTotal>53.00</ordersTotal>
                <prod>
                    <productCount>1</productCount>
                    <productPrice>2.00</productPrice>
                    <productPricePromo>0.00</productPricePromo>
                    <productDiscount>0</productDiscount>
                    <productName>Шампоан против косопад Loreal Density Advanced 500 мл.</productName>
                    <productNumber>30055</productNumber>
                </prod>
                <prod>
                    <productCount>1</productCount>
                    <productPrice>6.00</productPrice>
                    <productPricePromo>0.00</productPricePromo>
                    <productDiscount>0</productDiscount>
                    <productName>Маска за суха коса Loreal Интенс Рипер 200 мл.</productName>
                    <productNumber>30107</productNumber>
                 </prod>
     </order>
 </orders>
```

But whatever i try e end up like this:

```
     <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
     <orders xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" 
     xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
     <order>
       <order>
         <ordersID>0</ordersID>
         <ordersTotal>0</ordersTotal>
         <products> 
           <progducts> 
           <productCount>0</productCount>
           <productPrice>0</productPrice>
           <productPricePromo>0</productPricePromo>
           <productDiscount>0</productDiscount>
           <productNumber>0</productNumber>
       </progducts>
       <progducts>
           <productCount>0</productCount>
           <productPrice>0</productPrice> 
           <productPricePromo>0</productPricePromo> 
           <productDiscount>0</productDiscount>
           <productNumber>0</productNumber> 
       </progducts>
     </products> 
   </order>
  </order> 
</orders>
```

The problem is the names of the second and third class i`m using is geting listed as tags aswell inside the xml. So my question is: is there any way around this?
Here is my code aswell.
Classes:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Xml.Serialization;

namespace testXML
{
    [Serializable]
    public  class orders 
    {
        private List <order> m_order = new List <order>();

        [XmlArrayItem(typeof(order))]
        public List<order> order
        {
            get { return m_order; }
            set { m_order = value; }
        }

    }

    [Serializable]
    public class order
    {
        public int ordersID         { get; set; }
        public double ordersTotal   { get; set; }
        private List<progducts> prod = new List<progducts>();

        [XmlArrayItem(typeof(progducts))]
        public List<progducts> products
        {
            get { return prod; }
            set { prod = value; }
        }

    }

    [Serializable]
    public class progducts 
    {
        public string productName       { get; set; }
        public int productCount         { get; set; }
        public double productPrice      { get; set; }
        public double productPricePromo { get; set; }
        public double productDiscount   { get; set; }
        public Int64 productNumber      { get; set; }
    }

}
```

And here is the execution code:

```
        orders f = new orders();
        order or = new order();
        progducts p1 = new progducts();
        progducts p2 = new progducts();



        f.order.Add(or);
        or.products.Add(p1);
        or.products.Add(p2);




        XmlSerializer xmlSerializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(orders));
        TextWriter writer = new StreamWriter("Family.xml");
        xmlSerializer.Serialize(writer, f);
        writer.Close();
```

Thank you for any help in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Replace the `[XmlArrayItem(typeof(order))]` with `[XmlElement("order")]`  and `[XmlArrayItem(typeof(progducts))]` with `[XmlElement("prod")]`. That will remove one level when serializing the lists.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a serialization attribute to change the names of the XML elements or attributes you want to represent your class structure.  See [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms950721.aspx)

Comment: I do not need to change the name of elements. I have 2 extra elements(the names of the second 2 classes)

Comment: -1 for: there is no Serialization attribute and to name a property differently, you will need XmlElement or XmlAttribute attribute.

Comment: I said serialization attribute, not xml attribute.  Please remove the -1.  In .NET the generic name for any [someattributehere] nomenclature is 'attribute'.  If you confuse that with an XML attribute, that's not my issue.

Answer (score 0):

Just add another attributes to your property order like this:

```
 [XmlArray("orders")]
 [XmlArrayItem("order", typeof(order))]  
 public List<order> order         
 {             
     get { return m_order; }             
     set { m_order = value; }         
 }
```

That should work.

Comment: This only change the names of my tags. What i need is the tag created by the name classes to not be listed

Comment: According to @Fischermaen, you should get -1 for calling that an 'attribute'....  Ok I get it, you -1 other's answers when you are going to give an answer that is basically the same GG.

Comment: @Maess: Sorry, but XmlArray is an attribute.

Comment: I think your English is failing you in this, attribute has multiple uses and in this case, any "helper" you apply to a class, property or method can be generically referred to as an 'attribute'.  See MSDN: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/84c42s56(v=vs.71).aspx

Comment: @Maess: Be so kind and help me and my bad English: What is an attribute in C# spirit.

Comment: Take a look at the MSDN article link in my above comment.  In the case of your answer [XMLArray("orders")] is an attribute that you are applying to public List<order> order.  The fact that this is also applying to an XML attribute makes it confusing.

Comment: @Fischermaen I'm going to have to side with Maess here, not because he was 100% accurate, but because he was NOT entirely inaccurate and at worst a bit ambiguous. I think you should undo your -1 and give him a chance to correct his answer.

Comment: @Maess I understand this is your first -1 and it won't be your last, but try not to take it personally. Fischermaen (although incorrect to do so in my opinion) only downvoted because it is the correct thing to for the community when you see inaccurate information

Comment: @hugh: Thanks for moderating. Maybe I was too hard with that -1 and for the sake of the peace I would take it back, but the answer has to be edited first. (Told me the popup box as I just tried it a couple of seconds before)

Answer (score 0):

If you use the following classes which were generated using xsd.exe:

```
using System.Xml.Serialization;
using System;

[System.Xml.Serialization.XmlTypeAttribute(AnonymousType=true)]
[System.Xml.Serialization.XmlRootAttribute(Namespace="", IsNullable=false)]
public partial class orders 
{
    private ordersOrder orderField;

    public ordersOrder order 
    {
        get 
        {
            return this.orderField;
        }
        set 
        {
            this.orderField = value;
        }
    }
}

[System.Xml.Serialization.XmlTypeAttribute(AnonymousType=true)]
public partial class ordersOrder 
{

    private int ordersIDField;
    private double ordersTotalField;
    private ordersOrderProd[] prodField;

    public int ordersID 
    {
        get 
        {
            return this.ordersIDField;
        }
        set 
        {
            this.ordersIDField = value;
        }
    }

    public double ordersTotal 
    {
        get 
        {
            return this.ordersTotalField;
        }
        set 
        {
            this.ordersTotalField = value;
        }
    }

    [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlElementAttribute("prod")]
    public ordersOrderProd[] prod 
    {
        get 
        {
            return this.prodField;
        }
        set 
        {
            this.prodField = value;
        }
    }
}

[System.Xml.Serialization.XmlTypeAttribute(AnonymousType=true)]
public partial class ordersOrderProd 
{
    private int productCountField;
    private double productPriceField;
    private double productPricePromoField;
    private double productDiscountField;
    private string productNameField;
    private Int64 productNumberField;

    public int productCount 
    {
        get 
        {
            return this.productCountField;
        }
        set 
        {
            this.productCountField = value;
        }
    }

    public double productPrice 
    {
        get 
        {
            return this.productPriceField;
        }
        set 
        {
            this.productPriceField = value;
        }
    }

    public double productPricePromo 
    {
        get 
        {
            return this.productPricePromoField;
        }
        set 
        {
            this.productPricePromoField = value;
        }
    }

    public double productDiscount 
    {
        get 
        {
            return this.productDiscountField;
        }
        set 
        {
            this.productDiscountField = value;
        }
    }

    public string productName 
    {
        get 
        {
            return this.productNameField;
        }
        set 
        {
            this.productNameField = value;
        }
    }

    public Int64 productNumber 
    {
        get 
        {
            return this.productNumberField;
        }
        set 
        {
            this.productNumberField = value;
        }
    }
}
```

Then the following code:

```
var orders = new orders
{
    order = new ordersOrder
    {
        ordersID = 1,
        ordersTotal = 1,
        prod = new ordersOrderProd[]
        {  
            new ordersOrderProd
            {
                productCount = 1, 
                productDiscount = 8.4, 
                productName = "Widget", 
                productNumber = 987987, 
                productPrice = 78.9, 
                productPricePromo = 68.75
            }
        }
    }
};

XmlSerializer xmlSerializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(orders));
TextWriter writer = new StreamWriter(".\\Family.xml");
xmlSerializer.Serialize(writer, orders);
writer.Close();
```

Gives you the following output:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<orders xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
  <order>
    <ordersID>1</ordersID>
    <ordersTotal>1</ordersTotal>
    <prod>
      <productCount>1</productCount>
      <productPrice>78.9</productPrice>
      <productPricePromo>68.75</productPricePromo>
      <productDiscount>8.4</productDiscount>
      <productName>Widget</productName>
      <productNumber>987987</productNumber>
    </prod>
  </order>
</orders>
```